# how to make a bean prototype using only @scope("prototype) annotation in spring?

Tags: java, spring

i have this main class

```
public class Draw {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext  context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");

        Triangle t = (Triangle) context.getBean("triangle");
        Triangle t1 = (Triangle) context.getBean("triangle");

        t.show();

        System.out.println(t == t1);

    }
}
```

TRIANGLE CLASS

```
@Service
@Scope("prototype")
public class Triangle {
    private Point pointa;

    public Point getPointa() {
        return pointa;
    }

    public Triangle(Point pointa) {
        this.pointa = pointa;
    }

    public void show() {
        System.out.println("POINT A (" + pointa.getX() + "," + pointa.getY() + ")");

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Triangle [pointa=" + pointa + "]";
    }
}
```

AND SPRING.XML

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.demo" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.demo" />
<bean id="triangle" class="com.spring.demo.Triangle" autowire="constructor">
</bean>

<bean id="pointabc" class="com.spring.demo.Point">
    <property name="x" value="0" />
    <property name="y" value="0" />
</bean>

<context:annotation-config />
```

i know that to make a bean prototype we use scope="prototype" in spring.xml.
but i want to make bean prototype by using `@scope("prototype")` only.
i don't know why the above code is not working correctly.
I've researched a lot but couldn't find any answer

```
System.out.println(t == t1); this gives me true while ideally it should be false.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ApplicationContext has several implementations, ClassPathXmlApplicationContext one is used for XML bean configuration.

In XML ways you simply set the scope attribute in bean element.

AnnotationConfigApplicationContext is implementation of ApplicationContext used for Java Based Configuration means for annotation based configuration like @Bean etc.

If you want to use annotation way, then you need to define Java Based Configuration and need to use **AnnotationConfigApplicationContext** object.

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration{
   @Bean 
   @Scope("prototype")
   public Triangle triangle(){
      return new Triangle();
   }
}
```

Then obtained the bean as below.

```
  ApplicationContext ctx = 
         new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfiguration.class);

      Triangle triangle= ctx.getBean(Triangle.class);
```

Comment: now spring says a default constructor must be present

Comment: Yes because you have defined the parameterized one that's why

Answer (score 1):

Declaring `Triangle` as `prototype` has no effect as it is instantiated in your `spring.xml` as singleton.

The key is to ask for a new prototype bean everytime you need one.

This can be achieved by using a configuration class (and removing `<bean id="triangle" ...` from `spring.xml`:

```
package com.spring.demo;

@Configuration
public class MyProvider {

    @Bean
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public Triangle create() {
        return new Triangle();
    }

}
```

Usage is as follows:

```
package com.spring.demo;

@Component
public class MySingleton {

    @Autowired
    private MyProvider myProvider;

    @PostConstruct // will execute this method once app context loaded    
    public void doStuffThatNeedsAPrototypeBeanInstance() {
        Triangle t1 = myProvider.create();
        Triangle t2 = myProvider.create();
        ...
    }
}
```

Adding a @PostConstruct has the effect that the method is called once the application context has been initialized, as alternative to running things in the main method. This way, execution is inside a spring bean with the benefit of easily accessing other spring beans through annotations.

Answer (score 0):

for annotation configuration we use **AnnotationConfigApplicationContext** an implementation of **Abstract** **Application** **Context**

```
public class Scope{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    AbstractApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(TeacherConfig.class);
    Teacher tea=(Teacher) context.getBean("teacher");
    Teacher tea1=(Teacher) context.getBean("teacher");
    System.out.println(tea==tea1);
        }

}
```

**TEACHER CLASS**

```
public class Teacher {
public void print(String msg){
    System.out.println("TEACHER -->"+msg);
}
```

**TeacherConfig**

```
@Configuration
public class TeacherConfig {

    @Bean(name = "teacher")
    @Scope(value=ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
    public Teacher Teacher() {
        return new Teacher();
    }
}
```

**@Configuration to tell Spring that this is the core Spring configuration file equivalent to spring.xml, and define bean via @Bean.**

OUTPUT OF `System.out.println(tea==tea1);` is **TRUE**

Answer (score 0):

By extending the answer given by @AshishUpadhyay, I made couple of changes in code. The above answer is for singleton scope. For prototype need to make few changes.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;


public class Scope{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    AbstractApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(TeacherConfig.class);
    Teacher tea=(Teacher) context.getBean(Teacher.class);
    Teacher tea1=(Teacher) context.getBean(Teacher.class);
    System.out.println(tea);
    System.out.println(tea1);
    System.out.println(tea==tea1);
        }

}
```

Teacher class:

```
public class Teacher {
    public void print(String msg) {
        System.out.println("TEACHER -->" + msg);
    }
}
```

TeacherConfig class:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;

@Configuration
public class TeacherConfig {

    @Bean()
    @Scope(value=ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public Teacher Teacher() {
        return new Teacher();
    }
}
```

After running the Scope class the output is **false** which is expected in case of prototype.

Hope this will help someone.